# Toolbar icon for matplotlib not showing

Tags: matplotlib, icons, toolbar

The matplotlib toolbar icon doesn't show up with figure windows as highlighted in the red circles.

I am on the Qt5Agg backend and when I switch to TkAgg, the tk icon shows up.
The reason I am curious was that it was working fine until a few days ago but updating some packages broke it.

On Anaconda 5.2.0, matplotlib 2.2.3 and the image is attached.

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p5cv.png

Comment: Does this also happen if you run the code from the command line?

Comment: Yes - running from command line does the same thing